# Java calling from a class getValue

Tags: java

Alright so I'm trying to create a method called: setIncrement().  I have two classes I am using, FourDigit, which contains two TwoDigit objects that I have made.  I've called each one segment1 and segment2.  Their relationship is: segment1.segment2.  This method will increment segment2 and when it resets to zero, the method will increment segment1.

The problem is within this piece of code:

```
 public void setIncrement(){
    segment2.incrementValue();
    if(segment2.getValue == 0){
        segment1.value = segment1.value +1;
    }else{
        segment2=aNum%tooHighB;
    }
    getDisplayString();
}
```

It says: cannot find symbol variable: getValue() ???

Here are the classes:

FourDigits class:

```
public class FourDigits
{
/**
 * Fields
 */
private Digits segment1;
private Digits segment2;
private String displayString;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class FourDigits
 */
public FourDigits(int anyHigha, int anyHighb)
{
    segment1 = new Digits(anyHigha);
    segment2 = new Digits(anyHighb);
}

/**
 * Mutator method to set values
 */
public void setValues(int anyNuma, int anyNumb){
    segment1.setValue(anyNuma);
    segment2.setValue(anyNumb);
}
/**
 * Mutator method to set the increments
 */
public void setIncrement(){
    segment2.incrementValue();
    if(segment2.getValue == 0){
        segment1.value = segment1.value +1;
    }else{
        segment2=aNum%tooHighB;
    }
    getDisplayString();
}
/**
 * Mutator method to getDisplayString
 */
public void getDisplayString(){
    System.out.println(segment1.displayString() ="." + segment2.displayString());
}
}
```

Which is taking methods from the Digits class:

```
public class Digits
{
/**
* Fields
*/
private int value;
private int tooHigh;
private String displayString;

/**
* Constructors
*/
public Digits(int anyNum)
{
    value = 0;
    tooHigh=anyNum;
    displayString = "";
}
/**
* Mutator method to set the value
*/
public void setValue(int anyValue){
    if((anyValue < tooHigh) && (anyValue >= 0)){
        value = anyValue;
    }else{
        value=0;
    }
}
/**
 * Mutator method to add to the value
 */
public void addValue(){
    if(value < tooHigh){
        value=value+1;
    }else{
        value=tooHigh;
    }
}
/**
 * Mutator method to increment the value
 */
  public void incrementValue(){
    int incrementValue;
    incrementValue = value + 1;
    value = incrementValue % tooHigh;
}
/**
 * Mutator method to display the string
 */
public void displayString(){
    if(value<10){
        displayString="0" + value;
    }else{
        displayString="" + value;
    }
    System.out.println(displayString);
}
public int getValue(){
    return value;
}

}
```

Comment: You are missing an "=" sign in your `setIncrement()` function, in the `if` statement. it should be "==".

Also, a stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: A tip to prevent the error I mentioned is to reverse the order of your comparisons. so `if(0==var)` instead of `if(var==0)`. that way you wont get a mistaken assignment in your if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides what everybody said:

```
segment2.incrementValue()
```

Your class method `Digits.incrementValue()` is of type `void` so this comparison check will **never** work:

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() == 0){ //Corrected your equals operation
```

I would suggest doing:

- Create a getter method for instance variable `value` (as `value` is private) in the `Digits` class.
- Do a comparison check as in the example (assuming a getter for `value` is implemented):

Example:

```
segment2.incrementValue();
if (segment2.getValue() == 0) {
  //Do work....
  segment1.setValue(segment1.getValue() + 1);
}
```

Comment: I figured that value is private so that won't work, but I did make a method called getValue which is just return value in Digits.  Now when I use your suggestion it said cannot find symbol variable getValue??

Comment: Where is your implementation of `getValue()` method? Is it **exactly** like `public int getValue() {return value; }`?

Comment: it's in the Digits class, and yes, it is exactly like that and I even tried to test it within its own class and it works!!

Comment: Recompile again and test if that solved your issue. Otherwise, update your question.

Comment: Look @ my answer, you have `if(segment2.getValue == 0){` without the `()` (while I have mine). if you do `segmen2.getValue()` the compiler is looking for a `public int getValue;` variable and **not** a method. Since yours is a method, do `segment2.getValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

As well as using the assignment operator instead of an equality comparison, you're also trying to set segment2 instead of segment2.value. I suspect the block should be:

```
if (segment2.incrementValue() == 0) {
    segment1.setValue(segment1.getValue() + 1);
} else {
    segment2.setValue(aNum % tooHighB);
}
```

I can't see any declarations for `aNum` or `tooHighB`, mind you... and `incrementValue()` returns void at the moment, whereas presumably you want it to return the new value.

(I'd encourage you to make use of spaces to make your code easier to read, by the way.)

Comment: @Swaranga Sarma, it's Jon Skeet we're talking about :) He's the SO Compiler and debugger! LOL

Comment: For some reason though now I'm getting an error that I can't have VOID?

Comment: Yes...while everyone else was busy trying to get the first answer, Jon Skeet wrote the most complete one.

Comment: @jtm22...you have declared your segment.increment() as returning void...that would not work. What you need to do is that once you increase the value you need to return it. Or use another method like:  getValue().

Comment: @jtm22, see my answer to your `VOID` issue.

Comment: Hmm..getValue doesn't seem to be found..cannot find symbol variable getValue??

Comment: @jtm22: Yes, the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong - it's trying to find a variable, but getValue is a method. Updating my answer...

Comment: @jtm22: I've updated my answer, but really you ought to be able to work out the problem based on what the compiler is telling you, and where it's pointing to with the errors. Us just correcting each small mistake in your code isn't really going to do much to improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using '==' when comparing two numbers instead of '=' which assigns values.

e.g.:

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() == 0){
```

Comment: In the OP's question, `segment2.incrementValue()` is of type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() = 0){
```

And the compiler tells you exactly what's wrong: you're trying to assign to something that's a value, not a variable. Presumably you want to compare rather than assign, so the line should be:

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() == 0){
```

Comment: In the OP's question, `segment2.incrementValue()` is of type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this kind of comparison [which is an assignment instead of a comparison]:

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() = 0)
```

Shouldn't it be

```
if(segment2.incrementValue() == 0)
```

Also change your increment() method to this:

```
public int incrementValue(){
    int incrementValue;
    incrementValue = value + 1;
    value = incrementValue % tooHigh;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone got the `==`, so I'll point out a different error.

`FourDigits` doesn't have access rights to `Digits.value`. You should be using the `setValue()` method you have in `Digits`.

**Edit for update:**

```
if(segment2.getValue == 0){
```

getValue is a method and need to have parenthesis at the end of it. Instead you need this:

```
if(segment2.getValue() == 0){
```

Comment: setValue doesn't do what I need it to do here in this class.  I don't want them to set the value, I want it stoart from 0 and increment each time.  I made a method called getValue which is just return value; in Digits, but that doesn't work.  any ideas?

Comment: @jtm22: Basic increment with jsut get and set. `segment1.setValue(segment1.getValue()+1)`